# Два одновременных действия при нажатии на ссылку

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doRequest0(){
$.get('api.php?order_id=<?php echo $data_id_var; ?>&data_client_tel1=<?php echo $data_client_tel_var; ?>&count_call', {
   action: 'doFunctionOnServer'
}, function(data){
 });
}
</script>
```

Есть ссылка при нажатии которой выполняется код:

```
<a href="tel:<?php echo $data_client_tel_var; ?>" id="doRequest0"><?php echo $data_client_tel_var; ?></a> Кол.: <?php echo $count_call_var1; ?>
```

То есть, если кратко:
При нажатии на ссылку tel:0000000, должно открываться уведомление о том, через какую программу открыть префикс tel (либо сразу должна открываться звонилка, если нажали на ссылку в телефоне). Все так работает.
Второе действие, которое должно быть: Это отправка данных через ajax скрипту, который допишет в базу информацию о номере, на который пытались позвонить.
Если с первым действием все получается, то второе уже не выполняется.

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы выполнялось два действия при нажатии на ссылку?
1. Чтобы открывалась стандартная звонила на телефоне либо на компьютере, когда нажали на ссылку-номер.
2. В этот же момент должна отправится информация на сервер о том, что на эту ссылку нажали.
У меня не получается сделать так, чтобы сразу два действия выполнялись. Получается сделать либо первое либо второе действие.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А где собственно происходит привязка этой функции к обработчику событий? У Вас название функции doRequest0 находится в атрибуте id

Вам нужно эту функцию привязать к атрибуту onclick

```
<a href="tel:<?php echo $data_client_tel_var; ?>" onclick="doRequest0()"><?php echo $data_client_tel_var; ?></a> Кол.: <?php echo $count_call_var1; ?>
```

Comment: Все, понял, где я ошибся. Спасибо за подсказку. Все сработало, как нужно =)